How to download previous versions of pentaho-data-integration CE（kettle）?
Below is the official download address for the open source community version：
https://pentaho.com/pentaho-developer-edition/
But I found it only provide the lastest version, and can not choose the previous version (now it only provides version 10), so how can I download the previuse verison, like pdi-7/8/9 ce and so on

Check out https://github.com/ambientelivre/legacy-pentaho-ce

Only the maven link is still available here. I assume this will also disappear soon with the new developer version
(assuming it is ok to share this link since it is also mentioned on the official hitachi forums)
